# Bitset inside template declaration

Tags: c++, templates, std-bitset

I would like to know if it is possible to have bitset inside a template declaration like so:

```
ListData<bitset<64>>* hamming = new ListData<bitset<64>>();
```

ListData is class containing a T element like so:

```
template <typename T>
class ListData {
   public:
     ...
   private:
     T number;
};
```

The compiler says that the template argument invalid and that hamming was not declared in this scope.
Any idea?

p.s. I am unable to use C++ vector containers due to my assignment's restrictions

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://rextester.com/TDSWL71410

Comment: Is it C++11 or C++98?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
It turns out the compiler thought ">>" in:

```
ListData<bitset<64>>* hamming = new ListData<bitset<64>>();
```

was recognised as the overloaded operator >>.

```
ListData<bitset<64> >* hammingList = new ListData<bitset<64> >();
```

Thus the above fixes the problem.